# Drawbacks of using manually created temporary tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-performance, temp-tables, sql-tuning, query-tuning

I have many queries that use manually created temporary tables in MySQL.
I want to understand if there are any drawbacks associated with this.

I ask this because I use temporary tables for queries that fetch data shown on the home screen of a web application in the form of multiple widgets. In an organization with a significant number of users, this involves creation and deletion of temporary tables numerous times. How does this affect the MySQL Database Server ?

Answer (score 0):

Execution plans can't be optimal when you frequently add/use/remove tables when we would talk about databases in general. As it takes a time to generate an execution plan, the DB is unable to create one when you use described approach.